# How to work with jQuery UI tabs in IE 6

Tags: css, jquery-ui, tabs

I am not very good with CSS but with lot of trial and error I made this page that has jQuery UI tabs and looks somewhat decent: http://jsbin.com/uquvi

However, when I open this page in IE 6, to my disappointment the tabs don't seem to have curved corners.

At work right now they have a very bad implementation of tabs because they are creating tabs with  tags and it just looks messy. Also, they are currently achieving curved tab corners by having two gif images. I had seen jQuery UI tabs in many blogs so decided to run with it but now I am problems.

Can someone please have a look at the page and tell me how to correct this for IE 6?

Comment: See the answer on this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364946/jquery-ui-tabs-rounded-tab-corners-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
```

both properties are custom for Firefox and webkit (Safari and Chrome)

If you want rounded corners in IE you have to do them with background images.

In this [Matt Berseth blog post](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/11/jquery_tabcontainer_theme_with.html) you will find example how to do it, but basically you have to assign a background image with the rounded corner to the tab.

[Another way to do it in this link](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/achieving_rounded_corners_in_internet_explorer_for_jquery_ui_with_dd_roundi/)

BTW, the html of the web page your are referencing is very messy, with two `html, body and head` tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [corner plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/), which uses CSS when possible, if the navigator doesn't support rounding with CSS (as ie6), rounds with javascript.